# InvalidConfigurationException: The child node "key" at path "security.firewalls.main.remember_me" must be configured

Tags: symfony

I tried to update my vendor bundles in symfony2 using php composer.phar update, but when I did so I received an error after this line:

Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file

The error I get is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]           
The child node "key" at path "security.firewalls.main.remember_me" must be configured. 

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

My security.yml file has the following in its firewall section:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: webplio_site_dashboard_index
            #success_handler: webplio_site.login_success_handler
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout: true
        remember_me: true
        anonymous: true
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

where secret is defined in my parameters.yml file

My question then is what else do I need to do in order to configure the child node "key" at path "security.firewalls.main.remember_me"?

Comment: Looking at it here, your main: isn't indented. Could this be your issue?

Comment: Turns out that was a formatting mistake I made in my question, my apologies. I've fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change from

```
remember_me:
    key: "%secret%"
```

to

```
remember_me:
    secret: "%secret%"
```

Comment: Shouldn't be recommending removing the quotes.

Comment: Hi, No, change key to secret

Comment: I get that the key changed, but my point was don't remove the quotes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `remember_me: true` to

```
form_login:
    ...
    remember_me: true
```

Check the [security-reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) as to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Change key to secret and it works

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.